# MySQL user suddenly loses some permissions

Tags: mysql, user-permissions, mariadb

On CentOS 7, I have a MySQL (actually MariaDB) database user that needs all server privileges from a remote IP (to be able to use Navicat Premium to manage the database).

Somehow every once in a while this user loses its '*Create temporary tables*' and '*Lock tables*' permissions.

Using the mysql console I repair this every time with :

```
grant all privileges on *.* to 'user123'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass123';
```

I already did the following, to prevent the remote user permissions being reset :

```
touch /etc/securemysqldisable
```

but this doesn't prevent this from happening.

What is causing the permissions to be reset?